# Angular typescript: read characters with accent from CSV file

Tags: angular, typescript, csv, http, character-encoding

In my Angular (7.2.0) application, I'm trying to read a CSV file that is placed in the assets folder.
With the following code this works good.

```
this.http.get('assets/Test.csv').subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data.text());
})
```

However in the CSV file, there is a character with an accent (**û**) which is returned as [image], a question mark.

In the Network tab, the word also contains that question mark.

I tried to add some headers to the http call, to define the content-type and encoding, but without any success.

```
header.append('Data', 'text/csv;charset=utf-8');
header.append("Accept-Charset", "charset=utf-8")
```

Is there a way that this character is shown as in Excel? Or do I something need to change in the CSV file?

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: what are the response headers when you fetch the csv?

Comment: @JohnVelasquez I've edited my question with the response headers

Comment: hmmm the headers seems fine to me

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but - is CSV itself in UTF-8?

Comment: @Cerberus yes, I saved the CSV with Encoding UTF-8